# Android, Java moving a grenade at a sine wave

Tags: java, android, wave, trigonometry

I'm playing around with android and would like to try out to simulate a grenade movement with a sine wave. Would any one please help me with the syntax?

This is what I tried with the small math knowledge I have:

```
mPositionX += mSpeed;
mPositionY = (float) (0.5f * Math.sin(mTargetX * mPositionX));
setPosition(mPositionX, mPositionY);
```

But it doesnt really do what I excpected..

My mPositionX/Ys initial value is the spawnpoint of the grenade and mTargetX/Y is where I would like the sine wave to have done a half wave (like a semi circle) in other words; where the grenade should land.

My position values is in percentages so 0.5 is half of the canvas etc. if worth to mention.

Comment: "it doesn't behave as expected" what actually happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept you've used for a sine wave seems strange.
In a sine wave the equation is

> y=sin(x);

This should work for a sine wave

```
mSpeed=constant;
mTargetX = constant2;
mOriginalX=constant3;
mDistanceX=mTargetX-mOriginalX;
```

Now in the repeatedly called `onDraw`

```
mPositionX+=mDistanceX/mSpeed; //Distance divided by speed
mPositionY=(float) (0.5* Math.sin(Math.PI*(Math.abs(mPositionX-mOriginalX))/mDistanceX); 
            //Assuming you want it to go to pi degrees
            //Divide current distance by total distance * total angle reqd
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Just a slight problem, the curve is upside down :P It goes down, then up. How would I edit formula to make it go up then down?

Comment: @RasmusAppelkvist I've edited the answer. Made the position absolute. Now it should always go upward (hopefully)

Comment: What should I edit to make it go backwards? Like someone throwing the grenade from the other direction

Comment: Erm. Make the xPosition go in the -ve `mPositionX-=mDistanceX/mSpeed`